# WCF data synchronization

Tags: c#, wcf

Suppose I have a current bank account, and it automatically transfers money from my savings account when balance is low. So, I wrote below WCF code:

```
//Servicer side:

[ServiceContract]
public interface IBankAccount
{
    [OperationContract]
    double withdraw(double amount);

    [OperationContract]
    double enquiry();
}

class BankAccountService:IBankAccount
{
    public double enquiry()
    {
        return balance;
    }
    public double withdraw(double amount)
    {
        while (balance < amount)
        {
            transferMoreMoney();
        }

        deduct(amount);

        return balance;
    }

    public void deduct(double amount)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        balance -= amount;
    }

    public void transferMoreMoney()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000); 
        balance += maximizeTransferAmount;
    }

    private static double balance;
    private double maximizeTransferAmount = 100.0;
}


//Client side:
    ServiceReference1.BankAccountClient client = new ServiceReference1.BankAccountClient();
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {

                string tmpStr = Console.ReadLine();
                if (tmpStr == "")
                    break;

                double v0 = client.enquiry();
                Console.WriteLine("Current balance is:{0}", v0);

                double v1 = Convert.ToDouble(tmpStr);
                Console.WriteLine("Amount withdrawn is:{0}", v1);

                double v2 = client.withdraw(v1);
                Console.WriteLine("Remaining balance is:{0}", v2);
            }
            catch (CommunicationException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

The question is, when I have multiple clients calling the same service, the balance can be negative. How can I ensure that the balance would be replenished on time without ending up negative?

Also, I still have other clients that are only running balance queries, so if they only query, they should not be kept waiting, who to ensure this?

This is only an example illustrating what I need. This example illustrate the technical issue I need to address, but not the real case. I can't use database, because my real case is one that requires high-performance real-time calculation in memory, so database is not an option.

More basically, is there something that resembles "lock" in WCF service, when multiple clients call the same service that shares the same data?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

```
you must define behavior specific for your service wcf ( Singleton Instance Mode +  Concurrency Mode Multiple)

    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,
        ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
    public class BankAccountService: IBankAccount
    {

    }

Note : You can also define your behavior in config file
```

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your help. I added the service behavior definition as above. But it still didn't give me the result I want. If I have two clients each requiring to withdraw 90, while my balance is 100, then the first client returns a net balance of 10, while the next returns a net balance of -80, which is negative. What should I do?

Comment: Hello Mihael, in this case replace ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple with ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single

Answer (score 3):

Actually you must be using ConcurrencyMode.Single, concurentcy mode single will queue all call to service BankAccountService and request will be executed one after other. If you go for   ConcurrencyMode.Multiple you yourself have to implement thread lock.